# this picture has a digital look to it. How do you think it has been achieved?

Tags: photoshop-effects

I found this image on the internet and I noticed it has this render-like quality to it. How do you think it has been achieved?

[image]

Comment: I dont think this image has any render like quality to it.

Comment: Just looks like a normal photo to me -- the key is that the room itself had some excellent color theory taking place.

Answer (score 4):

**TL:DR** How was it achieved?  Most likely by using a phone camera.

I think the image has too much noise reduction, and possibly also too much jpeg compression. Also there's not a lot of dynamic range in the image, burnt out highlights, and very black shadows.

This is common when using phones or consumer grade compact cameras. These devices often apply aggressive levels of noise reduction and compression which can result in too much smoothing of textures, and loss of detail. The tiny sensors used in these devices often don't have a great deal of dynamic range either. Unfortunately, most of these devices don't give users an option to control how the images are processed. You just press a button, and out pops a jpeg.

With professional or semi-professional equipment, photographers have the option to do their own processing, and don't have to rely on the software within the camera to do it for them. Also the sensors are larger, and can deal with low light situations better, and can record more dynamic range. The optics (lenses) are generally better quality too, resulting in sharper images.

Just a note here, this isn't really a graphic design question. If you have photography questions, there is a dedicated photography stack exchange if you want to get into the subject in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

As Billy Kerr mentioned, probably just some automatic processing/filter applied by some phone app.

If you need to achieve something similar using Photoshop, you probably need to look at increasing contrast, shadows and saturation, while decreasing highlights. Also playing with noise settings.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a pro quality 24x36 mm sensor camera and a lens of the same league. Get still this result with the next receipe:

Shoot in RAW mode, develop the result as single shot HDR (add light to shadows and recover highlights without removing local contrast), insert strong boosts of saturation, vibrancy and clarity and use very low quality (=high compression) conversion to JPG.

To be sure there's enough noise in the shot use very high manually set ISO sensitivity in the camera. Convert it to plastic look by applying strong color and luminance noise removal in the RAW development process.

If the quality is still not low enough, recycle the JPG via Imgur and Facebook. Compensate possible saturation and sharpness losses by boosting them in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

A major factor in why this image reads as "CGI" to you is likely controlled lighting, so every surface is well lit from the right direction and nothing is in shadow. High-end studio photography isn't so much about the camera as about control of the lights so everything is lit in a balanced way. Cameras don't have the dynamic range of our eyes, so a composition that to our eyes looks pleasing can look dull or blown out in a camera.

An extra point is the "clean" look of the screens, often photographing a screen looks bad because of the screen having a different colour balance or brightness level to the room's ambient lighting. If anything in the image is photoshopped, I'd say that's the most likely bit. Especially as both show the macOS Big Sur default wallpaper despite it being a PC laptop.